# How to add bias and weight to neural network diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

I have the following code that I came out with help of this community, but it seems to be missing some elements that I still want to add, like the bias as a node and the weight as something written or a node, I don't know the best way to show it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\layersep{3cm}
\def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-2.5) {};  %%% <-- MODIFIED
    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {1,...,5} { %%% MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1,...,5, and the next five lines)
         \ifnum \y=4
           \node at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep) {$\vdots$};
         \else
           \node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$};
         \fi
       }
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
    }
    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {}; %%% <-- MODIFIED (from H\Nhidden-6 to H\Nhidden-3) 
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5} %%% <-- MODIFIED (1,...,12 -> 1...,3,5)
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** The result is something like these two questions already answered, which I couldn't do the same.

1) [Neural Network illustration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378450/neural-network-illustration)

[image]

2) [drawing a neural network with bias with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385119/drawing-a-neural-network-with-bias-with-tikz)

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: I made an example of what I am trying too achieve:[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217621/edge-weights-and-node-labels)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**sidenote:**

1. Please add always a **minimal** working example [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).
2. It would be good if you add an image of the result so that people can see directly, what you are expected to achieve. Images of other questions or answers are not helpful. A link is enough.
3. Please keep in mind to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. See the [How to Ask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying questions.

---

**Update answer refer to your comments + improved question:**

[image]

**MWE** (update version):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\layersep{3cm}
\def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50,},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
    bias/.style={neuron, fill=yellow!50,minimum size=4em},%<-- added %%%
]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-2.5) {};  
    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {0,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {0,...,5} { % <-- added 0 instead of 1 %%%%%
     \ifnum \y=4
     \ifnum \N>0 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \node at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep) {$\vdots$};
       \else\fi %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \else
         \ifnum \y=0 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \ifnum \N<3 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \node[bias] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {Bias}; %<-- added
           \else\fi %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \else %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \ifnum \N>0 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$}; %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%
               \else\fi %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%
         \fi %<-- added %%%%%%%
         \fi
       }
       \ifnum \N>0 %<-- added %%%%%%
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm,yshift=2cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N}; % <- added yshift=2cm %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \else\fi %<-- added %%%%%
    }
    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {}; 
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} {
          % \path[yellow] (H-0) edge (H1-\dest);
          \path[dashed,orange] (H0-0) edge (H1-\dest); %<-- added %%%%%
            \path[yellow] (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);};

    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {0,...,3,5} 
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5}{

               \ifnum \source=0 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \path[dashed,red](H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);%<-- added 
              \else %<-- added %%%
              \path[blue] (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);%<-- added 
              \fi %<-- added %%%
              }; %<-- added %%%%

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5}
    \path[green] (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);
    \path[dashed,red] (H2-0) edge (O); %<-- added %%%%
    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};  
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

**Just a  short starting point!**

Just to help you adapting the code. A starting point could be the following. I hope it will help you to see the real problem in understanding your code. I added a new row (called `\y=0`) and added in column `\N=2` ( is Hidden layer 2) a new node (`\node[bias]`). In general the option `minimum size=<..>` could be helpful for all node styles, see `bias/.style={...`. The headers are shifted with `yshift=2cm`. Dashed arrow from bias to output: `\path[dashed] (H2-0) edge (O);`. All changes are marked with `%<-- added %%%%%%`.

[image]

MWE (starting point):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\layersep{3cm}
\def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   shorten >=1pt,->,
   draw=black!50,
    node distance=\layersep,
    every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50,},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
    annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
    bias/.style={neuron, fill=yellow!50,minimum size=4em},%<-- added %%%
]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-2.5) {};  
    % set number of hidden layers
    \newcommand\Nhidden{2}

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
       \foreach \y in {0,...,5} { % <-- added 0 instead of 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \ifnum \y=4
           \node at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep) {$\vdots$};
         \else
         \ifnum \y=0 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \ifnum \N=2 %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \node[bias] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {Bias}; %<-- added
           \else\fi %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \else %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$}; %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \fi %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \fi
       }
    \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm,yshift=2cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N}; % <- added yshift=2cm %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }
    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-3] (O) {}; 
    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5} 
            \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
    % connect all hidden stuff
    \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
       \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5} 
           \foreach \dest in {1,...,3,5}
               \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3,5}
        \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};

    \path[dashed] (H2-0) edge (O); %<-- added %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was able to add bias above H1, but I don't know how to connect it to every node. I tried `\foreach` but didn't worked.

Also, the bias above input layer:
`% Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {0,...,3}
    \ifnum \y=0
    \node[bias] (I-\y) at (I*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {Bias};
    \else
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y-2.5) {};`

This didn't worked @Bobyandbob

Comment: The bias node is `(H2-0)` so you have to connect this node toanother node for example the output node `(O)` -> `\path[dashed] (H2-0) edge (O);`. - We don't know which connections do you need! I can repeat "It would be good if you could add an image of the desired result". Your question is unclear. Please tell us which adaptions do you need. - Off-topic: it sound i little bit like a "Please do my work for me" question :(.

Comment: I just saw your new image. Much better. I will see and try to help.

Comment: Thank you @Bobyandbod ! I was really trying to make it, but your help were amazing! Sorry if it seemed like a "do for me", it wasn't the intention.

Comment: You are welcome. If i find time sometime, *maybe* i will add some comments to my answer for clarification.

Comment: note for others - there must be 2 or more hidden layers, if \Nhidden{1} is given this won't run